# Angular 12 FormControls in nested formGroup inside of two FormArrays

Tags: angular12

I am trying to build dynamic form that has such structure:

```
Form
-|FormGroup
--|FormArray
---|FormGroup
----|FormControl
----|FormArray
-----|FormGroup
------|FormControl <-- Problem that I cannot bind this form control to input
------|FomrControl <-- Problem that I cannot bind this form control to input
```

On two specified controls I get error

```
Cannot find control with path: 'items -> 0 -> properties -> 1'
```

I just guess that it can be because something wrong with `let rowItem of items.controls[i].value.properties; let j=index`

Tried a lot of different sceanrious without success. For example:

```
let rowItem of items.controls[i].properties; let j=index
```

give

```
Property 'properties' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dsu7e5?file=src/app/app.component.html)

On StackBlitz it is also not working correct.

I will be grateful for advices on how to connect those FormControl's to inputs.

**Html code:**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<div formArrayName="items">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i=index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="word" matInput>
      <div formArrayName="properties">
        <div *ngFor="let rowItem of items.controls[i].value.properties; let j=index">
          <div [formGroupName]="j">
            <input formControlName="property" matInput>
            <input formControlName="value" matInput>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <button (click)="addWordProperty(items.controls[i].value.properties)">Add property</button>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button (click)="addWord()">Add word</button>
</div>
</form>

{{ myForm.value | json }}
```

Type Script Code:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-infinitive',
  templateUrl: './infinitive.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./infinitive.component.css']
})
export class InfinitiveComponent {

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      items: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          word: this.fb.control(''),
          properties: this.fb.array([
            this.fb.group({
              property: this.fb.control(''),
              value: this.fb.control('')
            })
          ]),
        })
      ])
    })
  }

  addWordProperty(control: any) {
    var items = control as FormArray;
    items.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }

  addWord() {
    var array = this.myForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    array.push(this.fb.group({
      word: this.fb.control(''),
      properties: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          property: this.fb.control(''),
          value: this.fb.control('')
        })
      ]),
    }));
  }
  get items() {
    return this.myForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<div formArrayName="items">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i=index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="word" matInput>
      <div formArrayName="properties">
        <div *ngFor="let rowItem of items.controls[i].controls['properties'].controls; let j=index">
          <div [formGroupName]="j">
            <input formControlName="property" matInput>
            <input formControlName="value" matInput>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <button (click)="addWordProperty(items.controls[i].value.properties)">Add property</button>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button (click)="addWord()">Add word</button>
</div>
</form>
```